# Почему событие не может поймать ошибку?

Tags: javascript

```js
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', function(event) {console.log
  console.log(event.promise); 
  console.log(event.reason); 
});

new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    throw new Error("Whoops!");
  }, 1000);
}).catch(console.log);
```

Comment: а с чего ты взял, что у window есть событие `unhandledrejection`? Почему ты думаешь, что в твоем случае оно должно сработать?

Comment: @Grundy промис завершается с ошибкой

Comment: Что-то я не врубаюсь, зачем суда тулите `setTimeout`? События еще какие-то тулите, изобретаете велосипед. Вокруг промисов уже есть `try-catch`. Почитайте документацию, внимательно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обработчик события [`unhandledrejection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/unhandledrejection) сработает, когда *Promise* завершится с ошибкой и на ошибку не установлен обработчик.

В вашем примере вам нужно вызвать метод `reject()` внутри промиса и убрать обработчик ошибки, установленный с помощью `.catch()`, тогда сработает обработчик события `unhandledrejection`.

```js
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', function(event) {
  console.log(event.promise); 
  console.log(event.reason);
});

new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    reject(new Error("Whoops!"));
  }, 1000);
});
```